# ECONNREFUSED Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am attempting to have MySQL and Node.js on the same EC2 instance. When trying to hit the IP of the sample I am using, I receive the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14) ...
```

My connection code looks like the following:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host  : '127.0.0.1',
  user  : 'student',
  password: 'default247',
  database: 'student'
});
```

I think my issue is that the database is not linked to my instance of EC2 but I'm not entirely sure. I thought there would be a way to link my RDS to EC2 using the elastic IP, but it is not obvious to me how to do that. Does the above error seem to point to an issue with MySQL connecting to EC2 instance? Or do you think the issue could be with my connection code? Thanks!

EDIT:
I guess I am confused... To clarify, I ran `npm install mysql --save` on the EC2 instance. Separately, I created an RDS database instance as I thought I would need to associate a database to my EC2 instance and was not aware of a way to create a database instance within EC2. My understanding of how RDS and EC2 are related is flawed. I am trying to find the easiest way to access MySQL through my EC2 instance. What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: What does it mean for a database to be "linked to an instance of EC2"? You said you have MySQL running on the same instance, but then you later say you are using RDS, so which is it? If you are using RDS then using localhost (`127.0.0.1`) as the database host address is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkB I made an edit to the original question. I am confused as to how/if EC2 and RDS are related.

Comment: EC2 and RDS aren't really related at all, they are separate services. If you create an RDS database it creates a completely separate server that is unrelated to your EC2 instance. Since you created an RDS server you will need to get the hostname from RDS and use that, instead of `127.0.0.1`. You will also need to open up the security group assigned to the RDS instance to allow connections from your EC2 server.

Comment: @MarkB Is there a way to just create a MySQL db and access it from EC2 without RDS? I'm having a very hard time finding a resource that explains how this is done without the MySQL database existing already. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just install MySQL directly on the server. Your EC2 instance is just a Linux server, you can install anything on it that you would install on any other Linux server. At that point it's not really an AWS question anymore, just a general Linux question.